# How to convert JSON array to XML element for WADL

Tags: json, xml, rest, xsd

I am trying to retrieve data from a web service and the proprietary ETL tool (which I have to use) requires a .WADL file for the connection to the REST service.

So far, I have created a .WADL file from the API endpoint with the help of SOAP UI and after that I have put the schema definition (for the response) between the `<grammars> </grammars>` tags. For that, I have converted the expected JSON output from the web service to XML and then to XSD with the help of an online formatter.

This works fine for most of the original JSON elements however when the  element is a JSON array (without names), my ETL tool is not able to parse the value.

To illustrate, the output from the web service looks similar to this (I shortened the output a bit):

```
{
   "report":    {
      "type": "overtime",
      "elements": [      {
         "id": "datetime",
         "name": "Date"
      }],
      "totals": ["51245123"]
   }
}
```

The XSD then looks like this (after I have already removed some unneeded elements with name "element" which the online converter put there as a replacement for the original JSON arrays (e.g. "elements")):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="report">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="elements">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="totals">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="element"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I use the above XSD in my .WADL file, then my tool fails while parsing the "totals" element because of a mismatch.
When I remove the complex type element named "element" and just use `<xs:element type="xs:int" name="totals"/>`, then I get values for all properties except for the element name "totals". This appears as null.

That means I can get data for the JSON array "elements" but not for "totals".
As I see it, my problem is only with 'normal' JSON arrays without a name because I cannot bind them to an XS element with the same name.

If I were to write code I would try to get the value from totals[0] but I have no control over how the tool is parsing the JSON response from the server. However, since I am able to get the values for all the properties (also from other JSON arrays which are using names/keys) I guess there is a way to also make it work for 'normal' JSON arrays.

Can anyone advise me on how to deal with those JSON arrays in XSD?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be useful to provide the intermediate XML. There is no fully standard mapping between JSON and XML as there are different ways of doing so (some are documented). This means that overall there are many meaningful ways that the input JSON could be mapped and checked against an XML Schema, and none of them is more "right" or "wrong" than another. Also, the ETL tool probably documents the mapping it uses and it is tricky to provide an accurate answer without this documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One formatter I tried online creates this for xml for my "totals" array:
`<totals><element>51245123</element></totals>`
Another one, give me the same without the sub-element:
`<totals>51245123</totals>`
I could not find any documentation related to the mapping for my tool but I have opened a support ticket with them to see if they are willing to help me.

Comment: Indeed, in the first case it is a complex type, and your original schema should work. In the second case, it is a simple type and then my alternate proposal should work. If none of these works, then the tool may be using yet another mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm feeling lucky today, I would still suggest to try this out for the `totals` element:

```
<xs:element name="totals" type="xs:string"/>
```

or if the tool can handle the cast:

```
<xs:element name="totals" type="xs:int"/>
```

(Looking at the way the `elements` array is mapped to XML, it seems that a simple type would be more appropriate than a complex type for `totals`).

Comment: I have tried both `<xs:element name="totals" type="xs:string"/>` and `<xs:element name="totals" type="xs:int"/>` instead of the complex element "totals" but the result is null/empty. 

With your solution, the description for element "totals" would be the same as for element "type". But "type" is a string and "totals" is an array with an integer value. How would I differentiate that in XML?

Comment: This is a good point, and the same applies to the `elements` array: it seems that the mapping considers an object and an array containing that object as equivalent, i.e., the mapping isn't lossless. Thus my guess that the same may apply to `totals`. I think that opening a ticket with the tool's team is the best course of action, as you are relying on their mapping and need to understand how it is done exactly.